# How to re-render parent from child component

Tags: vue.js

How do I re-render a parent component from child component when the child component is not called directly from the parent component, but through several levels of nesting, that is, from another child component that is several levels below the parent?

Comment: This is XY problem. Consider explaining your case, a possible solution may vary depending on it. It's possibly provide/inject that's been suggested

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't manually *re-render* any parent components. All updates should be initialized on your reactive data's changes. So make sure the data your parent component depends on is updated when the child component's data is updated.
It could be done with events popping up to the parent components.
BUT. With a deep level of nesting I use either `provide/inject` when parent/child components are tightly bound together (the child component couldn't exist without the parent) or some global/store reactive object.
Anyway there's no clear answer because there's no code provided.
Maybe first try `provide` in the parent and `inject` in the child.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
provide/inject only works for vue 3. My project is written (not by me) in vue 2 and I need to maintain and develop this version of the project. The other option is to use a global/stored reactive object is quite real. I have defined a global object bUpdate. But how to connect it to parent component's data. Including the field bUpdate: this.$root.bUpdate in the parent component's data causes the component to stop working. I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: The problem was solved by calling $emit on each parent until the change reaches the original parent. This idea was suggested to me by Peter Krebs.

Comment: @Boris_56 great to hear it's resolved